# DELETE AN ELEMENT OF A LIST IN PROLOG

Tags: prolog

I need to delete an element of a list in prolog, but it only work when you put the list in the consult for example: `eliminar(1,[1,2,3], X)`. it returns `X=2,3`, but when I wanna delete an element of the list "aves" it gives me false `eliminar(loro,aves,X)` it returns false.

```
aves([aguila, paloma, loro, canario]).
% Predicado para eliminar un elemento de una lista
eliminar(X,[X|Xs], Xs).
eliminar(X,[Y|Ys] , [Y|Zs]) :- eliminar(X,Ys,Zs).
```

I'm trying putting [aves], and it doesn't work

Comment: This is built-in functionality: https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=select/3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only capital words are variables (`_vars` are special case) in prolog. When you write `aves`, it will not be substituted to anything else.

If have declared, `aves([...]).` then to get that list back you have to query `aves(X)` which returns the list as the variable `X`.

```
aves([aguila, paloma, loro, canario]).
| ?- aves(X).
X = [aguila,paloma,loro,canario]
yes
```

So your query should be:

```
| ?- aves(X), eliminar(loro, X, Y).
X = [aguila,paloma,loro,canario]
Y = [aguila,paloma,canario] ? 
yes
```